# Can you tell me about the style of writing used in the Federalist Papers?

Tags: writing-style, writing

I've always found the [Federalist Papers](https://guides.loc.gov/federalist-papers/full-text) extremely hard to read.  They have many complex words, long sentences, subordinate clauses, and large paragraphs.  Here are two examples of sentences to frame this question.  I don't know that they're the best examples.

1.

> To multiply examples of the agency of personal considerations in the production of great national events, either foreign or domestic, according to their direction, would be an unnecessary waste of time.

2. 

> This is the melancholy situation to which we have been brought by those very maxims and councils which would now deter us from adopting the proposed Constitution; and which, not content with having conducted us to the brink of a precipice, seem resolved to plunge us into the abyss that awaits us below.

I'm looking for some explanation about this writing style.  Was this common for the educated in the Enlightenment era?  When did it come into favor, and fall out of favor?  Was it considered good writing, at the time?  Would newspaper readers (the intended audience) have easily understood it?

Comment: What are the 'complex words' in these paragraphs?

Comment: The syntax is much more complex than we like these days, and there was some influence of Classical rhetoric periods. But, yes, newspaper readers would have understood it. Newspapers in the 18th century were strictly for the educated class, and they appreciated what they considered cool language, just like we do.

Comment: Reading the passages more slowly (say at speaking speed) makes them easier to digest. The pace of life was slower then.

Comment: Yes, newspaper readers would have understood it, just as newspaper readers across the pond understood Dickens, who serialized his works in newspapers. Today, of course, such attempts would be commercial failures.

Comment: @JohnLawler Would it have been considered good writing at the time?  It almost feels like when I was in high school and used a thesaurus to sound smart.  Flowery words for everything.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It's still considered good writing by some, and certainly it was elegant at the time. This was intended to be a version of the debate going on at the time over what became the US Constitution, and the authors tried hard to convince people. These were written by several people and were anonymously circulated at the time. The opposite of tweets. Though the challenge of making one of their sentences fit a tweet is an interesting one.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53, which particular words here do you regard as 'flowery'? It is understandable that this way of writing seems unnatural to you, because you rarely encounter it, but to educated people of that era it came naturally, because all their peers wrote the same way. The words they used that may seem 'flowery' to you were well rooted in their vocabularies; they did not need to look them up in a thesaurus. Incidentally, the purpose of a thesaurus is to remind oneself of the words one is already familiar with; using unfamiliar words one picked up from a thesaurus is likely to backfire.

Comment: Multisyllabic latin-derived words used for poetic effect rather than to simply and clearly express an idea.   I mean look at the average syllable count of those sentences.

Comment: Which particular words in these examples are 'multisyllabic latin-derived words used for poetic effect'? While it is obviously true that many people nowadays find it difficult to read such texts, their difficulties have much more to do with the complexity of the syntax than with the vocabulary.

Comment: Most of those >= 3 syllables in these examples.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53, words such as *consideration*, *domestic*, and *constitution*, are regularly used nowadays, and it is hard to believe that it is their presence that makes these texts difficult for a present-day reader. They certainly haven't been used for 'poetic effect'. It thus still remains unclear which particular words in these quotations you find problematic.